# problem with chemical structure numbering

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to have a numbering of chemistry related structures to appear like this.

Compound 1a and 1b are useful, whereas compound 1c and 2a are harmful.

I would not like to generate the references myself. I can generate the image is in `png / jpg / bmp/ gif / tif / emf / svg` format not in `eps` format.

```
Compound    R1  R2
Toluene, 1a CH3 H
Ethyl benzene, 1b   C2H5    H
Chlorobenzene, 1c   Cl  H
o-chlorotoluene, 2a CH3 Cl
```

The modified question is "The question is how can i label 1a, 1b, 1c and 2a in the running matter. And how can i insert the reference where ever i wish." See the included pdf image!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. Your question as it stands now is very unclear. The format of your images has nothing to do with how they are labeled or referenced. LaTeX provides a `\label` and `\ref` system that will work for anything, and there are various methods for including figures as subfigures, including the `subfig` and `subcaption` packages. For example: [How to put two images next to each other with a) and b) labels?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13558/2693) and [How can I put three pictures with sub-captions in two rows using subfig package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26908/2693)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best of the chemical numbering packages is [`chemnum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chemnum), which is newer than [`chemcompounds`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chemcompounds) (my previous pick-of-the-packages),  [`bpchem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bpchem) and [`compoundcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/compoundcntr) (which is very awkward to use). With `chemnum`, each compound is labelled using the `\cmpd` macro. This creates numerical references, but allows us to subdivide using `.` to generate letters. I would combined with [`mhchem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) for the formula parts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,chemnum}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Benzene derivatives}
  \label{tbl:compounds}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
      Compounds & R$^1$ & R$^2$ \\
    \midrule
      Toluene                (\cmpd{Ph.Me})    & \ce{CH3}  & \ce{H}  \\
      Ethyl benzene          (\cmpd{Ph.Et})    & \ce{C2H5} & \ce{H}  \\
      Chlorobenzene          (\cmpd{Ph.Cl})    & \ce{Cl}   & \ce{H}  \\
      \emph{o}-Chlorotoluene (\cmpd{o-Tol.Cl}) & \ce{CH3}  & \ce{Cl} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

In Table~\ref{tbl:compounds}, compounds~\cmpd{Ph.Me} and~\cmpd{Ph.Et}
are useful, whereas compounds~\cmpd{Ph.Cl} and~\cmpd{o-Tol.Cl}
are harmful.

\end{document}
```

Notice that I've gone with the standard approach that chemical numbers are bold, which can be set using a package option.

Comment: Dear Wright,Thanks you very much. 
just out of curiosity, If required how do you take out the alphabets and looks like 1,2,3,4 etc and not like 1a, 1b, 1c etc.
Regards

Comment: @Anil You can reference the entire of a range of numbers by missing out the subdivision (after the `.`). So in the example, `\cmpd{Ph}` will print '**1**' and `\cmpd{o-Tol}` will print '**2**'.

Comment: @Wright, You mean number of characters minus 1 is the number???

Comment: @Anil. No, the argument to `\cmpd` is a label, and is freely-selectable in the same way that for `\label`. I picked `Ph` and `o-Tol` as these make chemical sense in the context of the table you asked about. I could have picked anything, provided that there was not `.` in it. With the standard settings the `chemnum` package uses `.` as the indicator for subdivision: you can alter this if you wish.

Comment: @Anil the syntax is `\cmpd{<label>.<sublabel1>}` = "**1a**", `\cmpd{<label>.<sublabel2>}` = "**1b**", `\cmpd{<label1>.}` = "**1**", `\cmpd{<lable1>,<label2>,<label3>}` = "**1**,**2**, and **3**", `\cmpd{<label1>.<sublabel1>,<label2>.<sublabel1>}` = "**1a** and **2a**"

Comment: @Wright and cgnieder:  Thanks you for the nice explanation

Answer (score 6):

Here is one approach to a compound numbering scheme (taken from a [duplicate post on LaTeX User's Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/latexusersgroup/4_eNBXzlwlc)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\newcounter{compoundcntr} \newcounter{subcompoundcntr}[compoundcntr]
\renewcommand{\thesubcompoundcntr}{\thecompoundcntr\alph{subcompoundcntr}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\compound}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% \compound*[<label>]{<name>}
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {#3}% \compound{<name>}
        {\stepcounter{compoundcntr}\refstepcounter{subcompoundcntr}#3, \thesubcompoundcntr\label{#2}}% \compound[<label>]{<name>}
    }
    {% \compound[<label>]{<name>}
      \ifnum\value{compoundcntr}=0\stepcounter{compoundcntr}\fi% Can use \compound[<label>]{<name>} to start first compound
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {#3}% \compound*{<name>}
        {\refstepcounter{subcompoundcntr}#3, \thesubcompoundcntr\label{#2}}% \compound*[<label>]{<name>}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
      \toprule
      Compound & R$^1$ & R$^2$ \\
      \midrule
      \compound*[toluene]{Toluene} & CH3 & H \\
      \compound[ethylbenzene]{Ethyl benzene} & C2H5 & H \\
      \compound[chlorobenzene]{Chlorobenzene} & Cl & H \\
      \compound*[o-chlorotoluene]{o-chlorotoluene} & CH3 & Cl \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some compounds} \label{tbl:compounds}
\end{table}

In Table~\ref{tbl:compounds}, compound~\ref{toluene} and~\ref{ethylbenzene} are useful, whereas compound~\ref{chlorobenzene} and~\ref{o-chlorotoluene} are harmful. 
\end{document}
```

The main command is `\compound*[<label>]{<name>}`. If you specify the starred version (`\compound*[<label>]{<name>}`), a new "main compound" is created (incrementing the first number). The unstarred version (`\compound[<label>]{<name>}`) does not increment the "main compound" counter, but increments the "sub compound" counter. If you specify a `<label>` (yes, this is optional), it prints the compound number. Otherwise, it doesn't. Whatever you specify in `<name>` (a mandatory argument) is printed as the name.

In summary, the available commands are

- `\compound*[<label>]{<name>}` = new "main compound" with compound number
- `\compound*{<name>}` = new "main compound" without compound number
- `\compound[<label>]{<name>}` = new "sub compound" with compound number
- `\compound{<name>}` = new "sub compound" without compound number

Effectively `\compound*{<name>}` and `\compound{<name>}` are the same. You reference the compounds by using `\ref{<label>}`, as usual, as seen in the example. Modifications to label representation and command usage is also possible. Care has been taken to allow starting the first compound with `\compound` instead of `\compound*`.

---

If your interested in a single compound numbering scheme, the construction of `\compound` is much simpler. Here's a view on one such construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\newcounter{compoundcntr}
\renewcommand{\thecompoundcntr}{\arabic{compoundcntr}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\compound}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% \compound*[<label>]{<name>}
      #3%
    }
    {% \compound[<label>]{<name>}
      \refstepcounter{compoundcntr}% Increment compound counter for correct referencing
      #3, \thecompoundcntr
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {}% \compound{<name>}
        {\label{#2}}% \compound[<label>]{<name>}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
      \toprule
      Compound & R$^1$ & R$^2$ \\
      \midrule
      \compound[toluene]{Toluene} & CH3 & H \\
      \compound[ethylbenzene]{Ethyl benzene} & C2H5 & H \\
      \compound[chlorobenzene]{Chlorobenzene} & Cl & H \\
      \compound[o-chlorotoluene]{o-chlorotoluene} & CH3 & Cl \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some compounds} \label{tbl:compounds}
\end{table}

In Table~\ref{tbl:compounds}, compound~\ref{toluene} and~\ref{ethylbenzene} are useful, whereas compound~\ref{chlorobenzene} and~\ref{o-chlorotoluene} are harmful. 
\end{document}
```

Using `\compound*[<label>]{<name>}` doesn't make much sense, since `<label>` is disregarded.

Comment: @Anil: If this answered your question, please consider upvoting and marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: @Werner The R groups here should _not_ be italic (a "mathematician's mistake"), and the radical numbers (1 and 2 after R) should be superscript. Subscript => number of R groups, superscript => different R groups.

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks - didn't know that; corrected.